# How to Code Quality on EXCEL VBA Code in SonarQube or Alternatives?

Tags: sonarqube, software-quality

We've have codebase with VBA/EXCEL. Which SonarQube plugin can analyze VBA inside excel or outside as text file. We can copy VBA to .vba text file if this is possible.

If not is there any other tool which can help us perform Code Quality on these languages.

Answer (score 5):

SonarSource provides a [commercial plugin for Visual Basic 6](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/visual-basic-6/). It may work for VBA if the syntax is the same.

Comment: This is VBA code inside Office (.XLS) and Access (.MDB) files. To my understanding commerical VB6 plugin is for VB6 projects. Sir, please clarify ?

Comment: The VB6 plugin can analyse files which use a VB6 syntax. It therefore cannot parse .XLS files but it may be able to parse .vba files.

Comment: Sir, current code code in inside EXCEL as vba code not as .vbs file. Its a test project so no issues. Is this achievable at all (like looking inside EXCEL etc. and then analysing code?)

Comment: If your problem is that your code is inside .xls files, then you need to extract that code to text files before analysing it. I don't know how to automate that.